# How to use fresh identifier in function parameter list in Scala macro

Tags: scala, macros, metaprogramming

In an effort to learn Scala's macro system, I thought I'd try my hand at writing a basic CPS transformation macro.  I've already written a fairly comprehensive CPS transformation framework for Clojure, so I'm pretty familiar with the CPS transform itself.  However, I'm getting stuck transforming function / method applications.

For the CPS transform, function calls of the following form:

```
cps(f(<a>, <b>, <c>, ...))
```

need to be translated into an expression of the form:

```
cps(<a>){ $a =>
  cps(<b>){ $b =>
    cps(<c>){ $c =>
      ... => f($a, $b, $c, ...)
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, the parameters of the generated continuation lambdas (e.g., `$a`) need to be fresh symbols so they can't inadvertently conflict with variable names in the lexical context.  So for each argument `arg`, I generate a fresh name:

```
val name = Ident(TermName(c.freshName))
```

(where `c` is the macro's `Context`) which I then use in the following quasiquote:

```
q"""cps(arg)($name => $remainder)"""
```

where `remainder` refers to the remainder of the computation.

The macro itself compiles fine, but when I try to use it with an expression that involves a function application, I get the following error:

```
... exception during macro expansion:
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fresh$macro$1 is not valid representation of a parameter, consider reformatting it into q"val $name: $T = $default" shape
```

However, I don't think it's possible to perform the recommended "reformatting", since there is no `$default` to provide.

Here's a minimal example that illustrates the issue I'm having:

```
def id[A](expr : A) : A = macro idImpl[A]

def idImpl[A](c : blackbox.Context)(expr : c.Expr[A]) : c.Expr[A] = {
  import c.universe._

  val name = Ident(TermName(c.freshName))

  //c.Expr(q"""val $name = $expr; $name""")
  c.Expr(q"""($name => $name)($expr)""")
}
```

Note that it works if you replace the lambda expression with the commented line.

So my question:  How can a name generated by `freshName` be used as the parameter name for an anonymous function?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/master/macros/src/main/scala-2.12/MacroImpl.scala#L101

Comment: @cchantep, care to elaborate?  There doesn't seem to be any function defined by the macro there.

Comment: If you read it carefully, you can see `TermName(..)`

Comment: @cchantep, ok ... I still get the same error, though, whether I wrap in `TermName`, etc. or not.

Comment: @cchantep, on closer look it appears the`TermName` is the fix.  Either I made a mistake or I failed to recognize the error had changed to complaining about "missing parameter type".  As that error indicates, I also needed to specify the type of the parameter, which I was able to obtain from the `tpe` property on the expression tree (e.g., `expr.tpe`).

Comment: (Also, I see now where the lambda is constructed on line 108 in the code you linked to)

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need a `ValDef` of the form `val $name: $T = _`, where the `_` is represented by `NoTree`. Initializing variables with `_` is valid Scala, setting references to `null` and numbers to `0` (i.e. the default values), but is also used as an internal placeholder when there are `ValDef`s (e.g. function parameters) but no sane default.

I’m on mobile here, so I can’t test it. In any case, you can destructure the value `q"a: Any => a"` in the REPL to find what the compiler normally sets as the default, if `NoTree` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `_` as a default value.  However, the question now is how to determing `T`.  In my contrived example, it's at least theoretically simple (although the details to realize it are sketchy to me at the moment).  But in the CPS case, I guess I'd need to somehow infer the type from the tree for each argument?